# Libreoffice apps not being assigned to specific workspaces in i3

Tags: linux, arch-linux, i3, workspaces

I use i3 and assign specific apps to specific workspaces using

```
assign [class="<WM_CLASS value>"] workspacenumber
```

But when I try this with Libreoffice it doesn't work. I run:

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

and click on Libreoffice Writer, and it gives me this:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "libreoffice", "libreoffice-writer"
```

So I added this line to my i3 config file:

```
assign [class="libreoffice-writer"] $ws9
```

and when I open the writer, it opens in the current workspace and not the 9th one.

I tried editing it to:

```
assign [class="libreoffice-*"] $ws9
```

and

```
assign [class="libreoffice"] $ws9
```

it doesn't work, but in the second case, when I open the Libreoffice app that is not a specific sub app, the main one, it opens in the specified workspace.
I also tried:

```
assign [instance="libreoffice"] $ws9
```

but same thing, writer doesn't open in the specified workspace, it opens in the current one. But the Libreoffice main app does.

Comment: This seems to be a known "feature" that is a by-product of libreoffice being a single binary that then somehow becomes a specific calc or writer etc. It seems the it starts off with a class of "Soffice" or "soffice.Soffice" or "Soffice.bin", then changes to "libreoffice" after opening the window. Try starting without the splash screen, option `--nologo`.

Comment: You should probably use `for_window` instead of `assign`, as this should notice changes in properties.

Comment: @meuh How do I use `for_window` to set it to a specific workspace?

Comment: @meuh I tried the `--nologo` option. From your comment what I understand is to keep the `assign [...] $ws9` option and then run libreoffice from terminal using the `--nologo` option. So I ran `libreoffice --writer --nologo` and it doesn't seem to open in the specified workspace

Comment: I'm not an i3wm user, but from what I've read you should be able to use
`for_window [class="libreoffice-writer"] move container to workspace $ws9`

Comment: That actually worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by *meuh* in the comments, I added this line to my i3 config file (with slight changes):

```
for_window [instance="libreoffice"] move container to workspace $ws9
```

and it works now. All libreoffice windows are opening in the 9th workspace.